# El-Dialog from Element Plus is not working in JavaScript code

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, element-plus

I am in the process of migrating Vue 2 to Vue 3. I was upgraded to Element Plus instead of element UI but following sample code is not working. can you please confirm whether Element Plus would work in JavaScript code? let me know if you need more info on this.

```
<template>
  <el-button @click="visible = true">
    Open Dialog with customized header
  </el-button>
  <el-dialog v-model="visible" :show-close="false">
    <template #header="{ close, titleId, titleClass }">
      <div class="my-header">
        <h4 :id="titleId" :class="titleClass">This is a custom header!</h4>
        <el-button type="danger" @click="close">
          <el-icon class="el-icon--left"><CircleCloseFilled /></el-icon>
          Close
        </el-button>
      </div>
    </template>
    This is dialog content.
  </el-dialog>
</template>
<script>
  import { ElButton, ElDialog } from 'element-plus';
  import { CircleCloseFilled } from '@element-plus/icons-vue';
  import moment from 'moment-timezone';
  export default {
    name: 'PDOTrend',
    data() {
      return {
        visible: false,
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```